# gluon javafx on raspberry pi 4

Tags: javafx, raspberry-pi4, gluon

I am sung instructions from gluon website to run javafx using openjdk11 and gluon javafx17 as per this link. i am using official rasbian buster desktop.

```
https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_setting_up_the_raspberry_pi_4
```

i do export ENABLE_GLUON_COMMERCIAL_EXTENSIONS=true and set it in the .bashrc
`export ENABLE_GLUON_COMMERCIAL_EXTENSIONS=true`
and rebooted my machine but still remote run from netbeans shows as under :-

```
Gluon Commercial Features not unlocked.
Set the environment variable ENABLE_GLUON_COMMERCIAL_EXTENSIONS and
check the file <sdk>/legal/javafx.graphics/gluon.md for license information.
[GluonDRM] eglSwapBuffers ok
[GluonDRM] realswapbuffer called
[GluonDRM] eglSwapBuffers ok
```

and program stops here . . . . .
please note that sudo -E is not working for me i am using only sudo as exec prefix in netbeans remote platform. my VM options are as under :-

```
-Dmonocle.platform=EGL -Dembedded=monocle -Dglass.platform=Monocle -Degl.displayid=/dev/dri/card0 -Dmonocle.egl.lib=/home/pi/fx/lib/libgluon_drm-1.1.3.so --module-path /home/pi/fx/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -cp dist/.
```

Thanks

Comment: The use of `-E` is precisely to access the env. variables defined in your .bashrc when you run with  `sudo`. Can't you modify the exec prefix to `sudo -E`?

Comment: env ==> shows all envirinment variables including ENABLE_GLUON_COMMERCIAL_EXTENSIONS=true            
sudo env ==> ENABLE_GLUON_COMMERCIAL_EXTENSIONS=true NOT present             
sudo -E env ==> ENABLE_GLUON_COMMERCIAL_EXTENSIONS=true is present in the output             
echo $ENABLE_GLUON_COMMERCIAL_EXTENSIONS returns true            
now i know the root cause and trying to find out how to use sudo -E in my system..........when i do man sudo on my machine , it does not show any witch for -E , its has -h -K -i -V -t but no -E

Answer (score 0):

From `man sudo`, `-E` is the shortcut of `--preserve-env`:

> Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables.

The NetBeans remote platform allows an *exec prefix*, so you can add `sudo` before running `java ...`. However, it only allows a single word. Using `sudo -E` as prefix won't work, since the created command line will be like:

```
cmd : cd '/home/pi/NetBeansProjects/HelloFX'; 'sudo -E' 'java'...
```

and that throws the error:

```
bash: sudo -E: command not found
```

So a possible fix would be adding `export ENABLE_GLUON_COMMERCIAL_EXTENSIONS=true` to a system-wide profile, like `/etc/environment`, which is a system-wide configuration file used by all users, and created with admin rights.

I've tested this and locally I can see:

```
$ sudo echo $ENABLE_GLUON_COMMERCIAL_EXTENSIONS
true
```

bit when running from the remote platform via SSH, it doesn't seem to be accessible.

Also, as you have commented, `sudo env` doesn't show it.

So while there could be a proper way to do it (maybe `/etc/sudoers`, but I'm not a Linux expert), there is a different alternative: remove the use of `sudo`.

If you remove the exec prefix `sudo` from the remote platform, you should be able to run remotely the app now. However you will see:

```
Udev: Failed to write to /sys/class/input/mice/uevent
    Check that you have permission to access input devices
Udev: Failed to write to /sys/class/input/event0/uevent
    Check that you have permission to access input devices
```

JavaFX needs access to the input files for mouse events, and for that you need permission, so `sudo` is just the quick way to get it.

However, there is another way to grant permission for input files, without using `sudo`: modify the permission rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules`.

Edit the file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules
```

and add at the end:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input*", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c '\
 chown -R root:input /sys/class/input/*/ && chmod -R 770 /sys/class/input/*/;\
'"
```

then save, exit and, just in case, reboot.

You should be able to run your app from NetBeans now via SSH, without `sudo` and with your env from `.bashrc`.